# Ajax simpre dentro de .html en la etiqueta <script>?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

he estado estudiando ajax, en diferentes vídeos de youtube y en diferentes paginas, ahora mi pregunta es siempre el script en el que va ajax debe estar en el .html siempre lo veo ahí, y por ejemplo he intentad pasarlo a otro lado como un archivo.js pero no me carga nada solo cuando lo dejo dentro de la etiqueta  del .html (codigo js y ajax) me funciona. es una buen practica esto ? esta mal ? porque ?

aqui esta el codigo que esta al final de mi body en el punto html. 
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y aquí esta el código que esta dentro de simular.js
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como resultado me direcciona a una pagina php. pero si lo dejo dentro del html si me da los mismo datos en el mismo html.

Comment: para hacer uso de ajax tienes que hacer uso de jQuery. si en el html funciona y no cuando lo pasas a un archivo externo es porque ese archivo externo debe estar cargando antes que jQuery.

Comment: Por favor, añade el código de lo que has intentado

Comment: @WFgo JQuery no es necesario para hacer nada, simplemente simplifica el trabajo.

Comment: JQuery es opcional para hacer AJAX pero no obligatorio

Comment: Mucha gracias por su ayuda, ya me funciono.

Comment: @juancamilovallejos0 Añade tu código, en vez de una imagen, por favor. Tan simple como un copia y pega :)

Comment: Esque no conozco muy bien la plataforma, soy nuevo. Y cuando pego el código se me desordena. Pero gracias por la sugerencia la tendré pendiente en preguntas futuras. Esta ya fue resuelta. Gracias por su ayuda. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

te comento:

> AJAX es la tecnología para hacer peticiones asíncronas; debe estar
>   dentro de una etiqueta script siempre al final del contenido HTML pero
>   antes de que cierre la etiqueta body.

Se ponen en la ubicación que menciono por que ayudan a no alentar el desplegado de la página por que el código HTML se carga rápido sin problemas y la carga pesada de JS se queda al final para no malograr la experiencia de usuario

Si intentas tenerlo disponible para todas tus páginas, necesitas crearlo como un archivo externo que por ejemplo se llame funciones.js e invocarlo del modo siguiente:

```
<script src="js/funciones.js"></script>
```

Si por ejemplo, usas jquery para AJAX la estructura de archivos debe quedar de este modo

```
 <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/funciones.js"></script>
```

Lo anterior para que las funciones que ocupemos de jquery esten disponibles para nuestro código que hagamos.

Es la práctica normal y general ordenarlo como te menciono, la última aclaración es también dentro de las etiquetas script puedes meter directo tus funciones javascript pero de ese modo solo servfirá para la página web donde lo declaras; lo mejor sería como te menciono mas arriba

Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias tu comentario ha sido de gran ayuda. me funciono poniéndolo en un buen orden como me sugeriste.

Comment: de nada por fas si te resulto útil podrías marcala como la solución, saludos y éxito en tu aprendizaje

Answer (score 2):

Separar el JS del HTML suele ser buena idea, a menos de que sea un código trivial.

No das ningún ejemplo de tu código para asegurarme de cual es tu error, pero en principio, y asumiendo que tu código JS esté en un archivo `ajax.js` en la misma carpeta que el HTML, lo que necesitas es cargarlo desde tu HTML con una linea:

```
<script src="ajax.js"></script>
```

Esta linea se pone tradicionalmente en la cabecera, aunque por motivos de optimización de carga se recomienda a menudo ponerla al final de tu `body`, justo antes de la línea `</body>`.

Y como te han dicho, si estás cargando otras librerías JS (como jQuery), asegúrate de que lo haces en el orden correcto. La tuya probablemente deba ser la última.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. :) ya me funciono.